# Call the popover hide event on angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popover

I have a question about AngularJS and Bootstrap.

The problem is that i have a popover info which doesn't close on iPad (exclusively). On desktop and others devices this works just fine.

What i want is to especifically call the popover('hide') event on AngularJS, so this way i can close that info popover. I tried to call the event manually but it didn't worked (popover('hide')), so i think there is a better way to do this.

What i tried is this:

```
popover('hide');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using angular-boostrap?

Comment: maybe something is on top of it that's why you can't click it?

Comment: Yes, i'm using angular-bootstrap  @ajmajmajma

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I don't think that because it works fine on another devices and desktop. I suppose that is not the issue. @MrNew

Thanks for your answer!